# How do you write your own IP protocol? (Assuming TCP and UDP are not suitable)

Tags: linux, protocols, ip

Assuming that you have determined that for a given niche case, neither TCP or UDP are ideal, how would you go about writing your own IP based protocol?

For example, if you're developing on Linux, where would you look in the kernel to "hook" your protocol in?

Where would you start?

Comment: @Ignacio Wouldn't learn anything then would I? Sometimes you need to experiment and try new ideas, if only to learn that it was a horribly bad idea to start with. I've written several simple protocols over TCP and UDP, but my current challenge is not a perfect fit for either. As I haven't worked directly at this low level before, I thought I would seek advice :)

Comment: Just curious, but how do either TCP or UDP not meet your requirements?

Comment: There are other established protocols also, such as [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol). I'll bet that there is an existing protocol that will work for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this through a kernel module. I would start by reading how arp works for example. That is a simpler protocol since userspace doesn't send packets out with it directly.

The entry point for creating a new network protocol is [`dev_add_pack`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/net/core/dev.c#L399), and the code for arp can be found [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.39/net/ipv4/arp.c).

Comment: That's what I was looking for. For some reason on my Fedora box,  net/ipv4 only has the netfilter directory in it. I guess I should have checked out the source from kernel.org and checked that before posting :)

Answer (score 5):

If your protocol can be implemented directly on top of IP, then it can also be implemented wrapped in UDP packets - and the latter has the advantage that it'll pass through existing NAT devices and firewalls that would simply drop your custom protocol.

Comment: +1, especially for experimentation that's a much easier path than writing a real IP-based protocol: it can be done in pure userspace.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on UNIX sockets and networking. It's not so much 'hooking' into the kernel, as it is opening a socket and sending your binary data over that.

Comment: @Matty I guess I can use raw sockets, but if I wanted built-in support for the protocol, I would have thought I'd need something more :)

Comment: @PeterM Built in support? You wouldn't create a kernel module to support a protocol. You're just exchanging bits in a pre-determined format. You'd have a listener (a server) at one end, and a client at the other that understand your protocol. I'd just use raw sockets. I'm not sure how else you'd do it.

Comment: @Matty Individual applications don't have their own TCP or UDP stacks though. For example if you ping a machine, the response is something I presume would be handled by the kernel rather than by an actual running application.

Comment: @PeterM ICMP operate on a different OSI layer, IIRC, to TCP/UDP. Look at something like nginx - when it runs, it opens up a listener socket and waits for connections. Nothing is compiled into the kernel, for example.

Comment: @PeterM - Oh, I'm sorry, I've misunderstood you. I thought you were wanting to build an application-layer protocol, not a transport layer protocol. Is there a specific reason why you protocol can't be at the application layer?

Comment: @Matty For the way I envisage it working, you would need an application to handle some of the to and fro of the protocol itself. I originally only needed one app per box to use the protocol but now I might need multiple apps to use it which makes it a lot more fiddly - hence the idea of putting the basics into the kernel so that all apps could effectively "share" it.

Comment: @PeterM It's rare that you'd need to develop a protocol below the application level. I can understand needing to develop a new application-layer protocol, but what kind of problem do you have that necessitates dropping down below this level?